# Yii2 : Getting class name from relation attribute

Tags: attributes, yii2, relation

I went through all API documentation of Yii 2.0 to find a way to reverse back to relation class name from a model attribute.

let us suppose that class Customer has a relation 
`$this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['id' => 'countryId']);`

and in a controller function the parameter was the attribute "countryId". How is it possible to detect the class name for the related model

Comment: `Country::className()` and `self::className()` (Customer) right?

Comment: @deacs `self::ClassName()` will return Customer class name, but the required is to get the country class name based on the attribute `countryId` defined in the relation

Comment: do you mean you want to get the classname of the relation from ANY attribute that *could* be a relation? like `countryId` or `userId` or `customerId`

Comment: @deacs yes, that is my objective

Answer (score 1):

Get the name of the class by removing Id from the end of the variable and capitalize it. But I cannot image any situation where this would be a normal development practice. You can also define am array to make this translation for the model.

You can try to use http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php to get the names of all the functions and try to guess the name of the relation / model based on the name of the field. If you name your classes and relation fields in a proper name then you should be able to try to again guess the model.

This still feels like a hack, create a function that returns the name of the model based on the field... easiest solution. I know you try to be lazy but this is a hacky way of programming.

Comment: Thank you @mihai-p but these suggestion wont serve my objective. which is to identify the relation model at runtime, and generate a create view modal based on relation model class to process via ajax.

Comment: I put in 1 more option, but I would still not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear on what data you have to start with here. If you only have a column `countryId` I am not sure. But say you have the relation name 'country' and the following code in your Customer model:

```
public function getCountry()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['id' => 'countryId']);
}
```

This is what I would do:

```
$relationName = 'country';
$customer = new Customer;
$relation = $customer->getRelation($relationName);
$relationModelClass = $relation->modelClass;
```

You could look at [\yii\db\ActiveQuery::joinWithRelations()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/136705c92b3e2908544fdff0ba2c754f0e2e145f/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L519) for how they do it.